# Couldnt clone the image tiles of map using jquery clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Working on the Open Street maps and [paperfold CSS animation](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/m/r/mrflix/ce26be858cecaf2b60021f86401337a3/paperfold-css_1333213378_demo_package/index.html).

I have placed a map in the

```
<section class="comment" style="height:250px;">
     <p> <div id="demoMap" style="height:250px;"></div></p>
</section>
```

But it couldn't display the full map. I don't know the exact reason but I guessed that in js library that couldn't clone the tiles of the map.

```
createFold: function(j, topHeight, bottomHeight) {
    var offsetTop = -j * topHeight;
    var offsetBottom = -this.height + j * topHeight + this.foldHeight;
    
    return $('<div>') 
        .addClass('fold')
        .append(
            $('<div>')
                .addClass('top')
                .css('height', topHeight)
                .append(
                    $('<div>')
                        .addClass('inner')
                        .css('top', offsetTop)
                        .append(this.content.clone())
                )
                .add($('<div>')
                .addClass('bottom')
                .css('height', bottomHeight)
                .append(
                    $('<div>')
                        .addClass('inner')
                        .css('bottom', offsetBottom)
                        .append(this.content.clone())
                )
            )
        );
    },
```

So will there be a way to clone the tiles of map or am I going wrong. If so how could I achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can access the tile elements you can clone them, but (assuming the interface is now the same) they appear to be absolutely placed `img` tags in OpenStreetMap - the `div`s are collapsed, so you'd need to either clone the `img` elements themselves (and use that instead, with different positioning, assuming it works with the library), or create a `div`, pull out the url from the image and apply it as a background for you `div`. As the tiles are numbered logically, if you know the area you want you could just skip that step, perhaps something like this:

```
var startX = 7,
    endX = 8,
    startY = 3,
    endY = 10,
    scale = 5,
    $parent = $('<div class="map"></div>');

for (var y = startY; y <= endY; y++) {
    var $row = $('<div class="tile-row"></div>');
    for (var x = startX; x <= endX; x++) {
        $row.append(
            $('<img />')
            .attr('src', 'http://path.to.images/'+scale+'/'+x+'/'+y'.png');
        );
        // or:
        // $('<div></div>')
        // .css('background-image', 'http://path.to.images/'+scale+'/'+x+'/'+y'.png');

    };
    $parent.append($fold);
};
```

The native format of OpenStreetMap itself probably doesn't lend itself to this particular library (particularly with its absolutely positioned images), so I think you'll need to mimic its layout with a more `position: static` structure, avoiding the absolute positions and splitting it into contained rows that can be folded.